How to send a conformation email using contact form 7 without OTP on wordpress?
I use contact form 7 for my wordpress contact form as well
now I need configure my contact form with conformation email sending without OTP use. how could I create with conformation email on wordpress using contact form 7

There is a feature already available in contactform7.
Go to the backend and in MAIL tab, you will see mail(2).
Configure the values and place holders, so that it will trigger out an email as the usual email to the recipient does.
This mail(2) will be sent only if the mail first configured values are sent.
Also refer to CF7 autoresponder FAQ docs.

Mail(2) is using for Autoresponser. but I need first send verification link to sender via email without otp
